# Why did Phantom 2040 always say "Aim, Lock, Fire!"

Tags: plot-device, phantom-2040

This guy...

[image]

...would *always* say "Aim, Lock, Fire!" whenever he fired his gun thing. Why did he do that?

Comment: I don't know why he would do it specifically, but I've found reference to the phrasing being used for weapons with guidance systems such as missiles. You aim at your target, lock in, and then fire and forget. I know that one of his primary weapons is a "thought-activated smart gun". Did it track enemies?